# AWS Route 53 redirection does not work as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-route53

We want to redirect our oldwebsite.com to newwebsite.com and both of the domains are managed in AWS Route53. The developer who set this up originally is not reachable.

I created an S3 bucket for oldwebsite.com and set it to redirect to newwebsite.com over http. Then on the Route53 hosted zone of oldwebsite.com, I chose the S3 bucket I created as an Alias name for the Type 'A' record set.

Our oldwebsite.com is down. I am pretty sure I have set the right values, but the oldwebsite.com still shows one of those "there is no website here, buy this website" type pages.

Further more, if I type www.oldwebsite.com, then that page opens, but if I type simply oldwebsite.com, it opens a 404 page not found on Hostgator.

Any help on where to check would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are getting one of those "there is no website here, buy this website" type pages then the DNS for that domain name is not actually being managed by Route53.

Comment: @MarkB That's what I suspected too. Technically, it is not a "buy this domain page", but it does show some ads. When I look at the Route53 page, it shows both the domains, and my boss also says that the domain was transferred. Would deleting the oldwebsite record set and zone determine this?

Comment: You can use `dig ns oldwebsite.com` (No `www`) to check the nameservers for the domain. The domains may appear in your route53 panel but unless the nameservers are set to route53, it won’t be used. If the nameservers are incorrect, it sounds like you need to contact hostgator or whoever you bought the domain from.

Comment: You can go here to see who the domain host actually is: https://www.internic.net/whois.html

Comment: I looked up my domain on mxtoolbox.com and the DNS Check says, Your DNS hosting provider is "HostGator". Does that mean I need to configure my redirect on HostGator?

Comment: No, you don't have to use HostGator as your DNS provider. Your other option is to  [set nameserver records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html#migrate-dns-change-name-servers-with-provider) to use route53, then do the redirect using AWS.

Comment: @Alasdair where would I set the nameserver records? In Hostgator, right? I am trying to get the old credentials now.

Comment: It's hard to give a definitive answer when your question is about `oldwebsite.com`. If hostgator is where you registered the domain, then yes. But it's also possible that you registered the domain somewhere else.